# How to tell whether Magento 2 site is EE or CE

Tags: magento2, admin, magento-enterprise, magento-community, version

What is the easiest/fastest way to check if a **Magento 2** site is on EE or CE?

Preferably via the admin if possible.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can get this information for any Magento2 install from Magento's official endpoint, by opening this URL in your browser: `http://www.example.com/magento_version`

That will give data like:
`Magento/2.1 (Enterprise)`
or:
`Magento/2.1 (Community)`

cf. http://magento2-demo.nexcess.net/magento_version

Comment: It doesn't get much easier than that! Thanks.

Comment: This works only if the Magento_Version module is active. Information like version and type of the platform can help hackers in an event of potential vulnerability discovery. This is why some websites deactivate this module on their store and the link redirects to a 404 page. To deactivate the Magento_Version module you can use this command: `php bin/magento module:disable Magento_Version`

Answer (score 2):

You can detect if a website is running Magento Enterprise Edition by hitting website_base_url/giftcard/customer in your browser. If you get a 404 Page Not Found error then that means they are NOT running MEE (Magento Enterprise Edition). If you get redirected to a login page that means they ARE most likely running MEE.

More Info [Here](https://jayelkaake.wordpress.com/2013/06/03/check-if-a-website-is-running-magento-community-or-enterprise-edition/)

Comment: This is accurate on the two sites I tested it on, if nobody comes up with an easier method I'll mark this as accepted.